# CakePHP, jQuery - Add data attribute to anchor

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, attributes

I'm looking for a way to insert a data attribute to my table anchors in CakePHP. It automatically generates the following code, but I have no clue on how to alter this in a way where I make it a data-target attribute.

The reason I want to achieve this is because I'm linking to different div's on the same page and want to **prevent the page from reloading**. Do I have to insert a `preventDefault()` from jQuery? And if so, how to do so?

This is my current code:

```
<?php foreach ($servers as $server): ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?= $this->Number->format($server->id) ?></td>
     <td><?= h($server->url) ?></td>
     <td><?= h($server->description) ?></td>
     <td><?= h($server->Timestamp) ?></td>
     <td class="actions">
         <?= $this->Html->link('View', array('#' => 'admin-view-' . $server->id)) ?>
         <?= $this->Html->link('Edit', array('#' => 'admin-edit-' . $server->id)) ?>
     </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here's the result I'm looking for; it has to be done using the CakePHP conventions (don't mind the list item):

```
<a data-target="admin-edit">Edit</a>
<a data-target="admin-view">View</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried this:-

```
<?= $this->Html->link('View',array('#' => 'admin-view-' . $server->id,'data-target'=>"admin-view");?>
<?= $this->Html->link('Edit',array('#' => 'admin-view-' . $server->id,'data-target'=>"admin-edit");?>
```

To prevent from page reload, create a link with `href="javascript:void(0);"` like below:-

```
<?= $this->Html->link('View','javascript:void(0);',array('#' => 'admin-view-' . $server->id,'data-target'=>"admin-view");?>
<?= $this->Html->link('Edit','javascript:void(0);',array('#' => 'admin-view-' . $server->id,'data-target'=>"admin-edit");?>
```

If you want to prevent through jQuery (not with the above code) then:-

```
$('link').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //rest your code
});
```

Note:- Make sure that jQuery library is added before this code and this code must be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you! As it's still an anchor, do you know how to prevent the page from reloading once you click the anchor (preferably with jQuery)?

Comment: @Levano  yes check the answer pls. glad to help you:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the details about **CakePHP** *HtmlHelper* `link` method

**CakePHP** `link` methods takes 3 arguments as its parameters.

- **Title**  [String]
- **Url**   [String or Array]
- **Options/Attributes** [Array]

**Syntax :**

```
 $this->Html->link($title, $url = null, array $options = []);
```

**Example :**

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   'Title',
   '/path/to/url', #OR ['controller'=>'','action'=>'','others']
   [
     'class' => 'button',
     'target' => '_blank',
     'data-url'=>'#',
     'data-path'=>'',
     /*Other attributes*/
   ]
);
```

Here is the details about [Creating Links in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)

> For your problem, If no need `href=''` in `<a>` tag, Then you can use `button` or other tags instead of `<a>` tag.

Comment: for the details +1

Comment: Thank you! :) +1 also @AlivetoDie